# xcode CGRectMake dimensions are messing up image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a scratch off image that I have covering a second image. The navigation item takes up 63 pixels in height, and I have a button at the bottom of my page that will direct the user to the next page.

When I draw a rectangle with the coordinates `CGRectMake(0, 63, mainScreenwidth, mainScreenheight - 63)];` The image displays perfectly, however it covers up the button at the bottom of the page. When I tell the height to be `mainScreenheight - 126` (63 pixels from the bottom) the image messes up and looks like the screenshot below:

[image: Zoomed out view of Image not drawing correctly]

If I then change starting y coordinate to `CGRectMake(0, 100, mainScreenwidth, mainScreenheight - 63)];` then the messed up chunks measure 100 in height instead of 63.

Below is my ViewController.

```
ScratchableView *scratchableView = [[ScratchableView alloc]initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 63, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width, 
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height - 126)];
```

Below is my View.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width, ([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height - 126));
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"scratchcover2.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        scratchable = newImage.CGImage;

        width = CGImageGetWidth(scratchable);
        height = CGImageGetHeight(scratchable);

        self.opaque = NO;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

        CFMutableDataRef pixels = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height );
        alphaPixels = CGBitmapContextCreate(CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( pixels )  , width , height , 8 , width , colorspace , (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNone );
        provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(pixels);


        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(alphaPixels, frame);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(alphaPixels, 20.0);
        CGContextSetLineCap(alphaPixels, kCGLineCapRound);

        CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(width, height, 8, 8, width, provider, nil, NO);

        scratched = CGImageCreateWithMask(scratchable, mask);

        CGImageRelease(mask);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CGRectMake` 's `CGFloat y` was messing up the image. The only solution I could find was to set the `CGFloat y` value to  `0` and alter the image by adding in that many pixels to the top.

From:

```
CGRectMake(0, 63, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width, 
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height - 126)];
```

To:

```
// image height + 63px
CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width, 
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height - 63)];
```